# a way to have an model attribute  which is not persist in database as a table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using **Rails v2.3.2**.

I have a model:

```
class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base

  tag_nr = rand(2007)

end
```

The `Cars` model is mapped to the `cars` table in **database** with columns `name`, `owner`.

As you see above, there is also a `tag_nr` which is basically a **random number**.

I would like to have each **instance object** of `Cars` **class** hold a **random number** generated like above. **But** I do not want to have this random number be stored in database. And in future, I can access this instance object's `tag_nr` by:

```
nr = CAR_INSTANCE.tag_nr
```

And the `nr` now is the **same** as the `tag_nr` first generated for this Cars instance object.

So, where and how should I define this random number in my Car model?

**-----------What I tried is:-----------**

```
class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init

  attr_accessor :tag_nr

  def init
    @tag_nr = rand(2007)
  end
end
```

But if I retrieve a car from database and try to access `tag_nr`, I got `nil`:

```
@c=Cars.first
@c.tag_nr.nil? # it returns true
```

So, how can I have an model attribute(like `tag_nr`) which is not persist in database as a table column but can be accessed as an attribute?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with what you need is in the part where you say you want to be able to access the *same* random number over and over again.

You're asking for this number to persist, even though you're wanting to *not* store it in the database...

Either information persists... or it doesn't. Information that persists must be stored somewhere. Currently your persistent data is stored in the database.

You can see the problem here, I hope.

Any number you generate will last only so long as the object lasts... ie for the duration of a single request/response... and then it will disappear, because you are not persisting it in the place where data is persisted (the database).

If single-response duration is all that's need, then the solutions already offered here are the best you can get.

The alternatives are:

1. store it in the db (it's the only way to be sure)
2. find some way of hashing on a unique-and-non-changable aspect of the
   data in your model. eg run MD5 or SHA1 over the records
   id+created_at timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ActiveSupport::Memoizable

  def tag_nr
    rand(2007)
  end
  memoize :tag_nr
end
```

from: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/59-use-memoization

Comment: Is it supported by Rails v2.3.2?

Comment: Looks like you are in luck, @Leem.fin ... http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M001213&name=memoize

Comment: No, it does not work as I expected, it always return me different tag_nr for the same instance object retrieved from database. It always generate a new random number when I retrieve the instance from database and access tag_nr, I need it to memorize the first generated number as the tag_nr value instead of generating new value whenever I access tag_nr that's why my question mean to ask a way to access it as a model attribute but not stored in database.

Comment: Between different requests?  Perhaps break out a singleton to track random numbers (via a hash) per Car.id or something, it seems a bit overengineered though.  How long do you need persistence?  Does it need to last between server deaths?  If so you need to write it to some store like db/file.  Else you could look at something like memcached perhaps, but it will eventually expire it.

Comment: If you don't want to store it, I'd drop the randomness and make it a deterministic calculated value

Comment: @ Kevin, the code is just a sample. In reality, the random number is used as a key for encryption of the model's one attribute (key is randomly generated for each instance object), I do not want to store this key into database for the sake of security. I would like to access the key however when I retrieve a instance from database. Hope you got what I mean.

Comment: So it's the equivalent of a password?  I'm not sure how to get around storing it. Sounds a bit like you're trying to use the random number as a salt, but generally they are safe to store with the encrypted field as long as the passphrase is not stored.  Do you have more detail?

Comment: Yes, it is used to encrypt a password code of each car instance. I need to decrypt it once I retrieve a car instance from database.

Comment: @Leem.fin there is no way around it, if you wish to decrypt it, you have to store it somewhere.

Comment: Shouldn't a rails (any) object "persist" during the duration of it's lifetime? If I create an instance of a class in java,c#,c++,php,python,smalltalk,lisp etc etc that object resides in memory and I can access all of its available attributes until it is freed. Why would you _not_ want to do this? What if you wanted to pass something specific about the object's state to the browser, or a message or meta-data or a calculated value? Why are you not given memory to store an instance when it is called? That makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be

```
class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init

  attr_accessor :tag_nr

  def init
    self.tag_nr = rand(2007)
  end
end
```

Example output from a Drug model (just because it was what I was working on at the time)

```
> d = Drug.first

=> #<Drug id: 1, name: "NSAIDs", category: "NSAID", comment: "Non-steroidal anti-inflammatory", created_at: "2011-11-23 17:46:22", updated_at: "2011-11-23 17:46:22">

> d.tag_nr

=> 1069

> d = Drug.last

=> #<Drug id: 6, name: "Antihypertensives", category: "ANTIHYPERTENSIVE", comment: "", created_at: "2011-11-23 17:46:22", updated_at: "2011-11-23 17:46:22">

> d.tag_nr

=> 1838

> d = Drug.first

=> #<Drug id: 1, name: "NSAIDs", category: "NSAID", comment: "Non-steroidal anti-inflammatory", created_at: "2011-11-23 17:46:22", updated_at: "2011-11-23 17:46:22">

> d.tag_nr

=> 800
```

There is nothing to stop a collision between the random numbers (ie two different instances could return the same number).

Comment: But with your code, the tag_nr will be a class variable. I need a per instance variable, which means each instance of Car class has different tag_nr.

Comment: Pretty sure that the self keyword refers to the virtual attribute in that instance of the class not a class variable. A class variable would be @@tag_nr (tbh never really use class variables)? But hey give it a go and see if it works :P

Comment: I still got nil....is @tag_nr and self.tag_nr both define the instance variable? What the difference between the two way of defining instance variable?

Comment: As far as I can see the @tag_nr variable is just a stand-alone variable that is defined within the init method (not actually associated with the instance of the class). So if you wanted to access that variable in your example you would use '@tag_nr' not '@c.tag_nr'.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this task can't be solved. As I understand you want next: you have a Car in your DB and

```
car = Car.find(10)
car.tag_nr         # assume this expression returns 100
...                # some code here
other_car = Car.find(10)
car.tag_nr         # this expression returns 100
```

correct?

if yes you have to pay more attention to `=` operator which createc new object each time you use it you can check it with `object_id`

```
irb(main):074:0> "abs".object_id
=> 21413208
irb(main):075:0> "abs".object_id
=> 20742936
irb(main):076:0> a = "abs"
=> "abs"
irb(main):077:0> a.object_id
=> 21493488
irb(main):078:0> a = "abs"
=> "abs"
irb(main):079:0> a.object_id
=> 21172272
```

since all objects are different they have different values for instance variables

Comment: What kind of engineer are you saying that a problem has no solution? Joking!